# Memory usage in SignalR restarts ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-management, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I am piloting an online game written in ASP.NET MVC (C#), using SignalR for the real-time aspects of the game, and hosted as an Azure web app. It is a fairly simple table-style game, but I'm running into a problem where under peak load (evenings and weekends), the app uses too much memory and the worker process is automatically restarted.

Here is a rough code outline of my SignalR connection class (with things like logging, null checking, etc.) removed:

```
namespace MyApp.Connections
{
    public class GameConnection : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId, bool stopCalled)
        {
            Game game = GameService.GetGameByConnectionId(connectionId);
            List<Task> connectionTasks = new List<Task>();
            Player player = game.GetPlayer(connectionId);

            game.RemovePlayer(player);

            foreach (Player playerToUpdate in game.Players)
            {
                GameActionResponse response = new GameActionResponse(game);
                response.Message = string.Format("Player '{0}' has left the game.", player.Name);
                connectionTasks.Add(Connection.Send(playerToUpdate.ConnectionId, response));
            }          

            return Task.WhenAll(connectionTasks);
        }

        protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
        {
            Game game = GameService.GetGameByConnectionId(connectionId);
            List<Task> connectionTasks = new List<Task>();
            Player actingPlayer = game.GetPlayer(connectionId);

            GameAction action = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameAction>(data);
            GameActionResponse response = new GameActionResponse(game);
            game.ProcessAction(action, actingPlayer, response);

            foreach (Player playerToUpdate in game.Players)
            {
                response.Message = response.Description;
                response.From = actingPlayer.Name;
                connectionTasks.Add(Connection.Send(playerToUpdate.ConnectionId, response));
            }

            return Task.WhenAll(connectionTasks);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm just responding to messages, using them to change the state of the game (keying off of connection ID to determine the correct player), then replying with a new game state (my GameActionResponse class) to the players. I don't use Connection.Broadcast because I need to tailor the response for each player (although that code isn't shown above).

I got Azure to give me a memory dump of w3wp.exe when it was running under fairly heavy load, ran it through the profiler in Visual Studio, and here is the result, sorted by inclusive size:

[image: Memory usage]

This points to a problem in SignalR or (more likely) my usage of it. My question is this: am I doing something fundamentally wrong in the way I am handling SignalR connections and messages?

Could it be the size and volume of messages? A typical client -> server message is way less than 1K (containing only the action the player took), but the server -> client response messages can be anywhere from 5-10K up to 30K for "full refresh" messages.

Comment: Try decreasing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.configuration.iconfigurationmanager.defaultmessagebuffersize(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Have you refereed to this [tutorial](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance) about the Performance of SignalR?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Pawel and @Bruce-MSFT! There are definitely some ways I could decrease the message size (e.g. shortening the property names as the article suggests). Do you think it would be feasible to actually compress the JSON payload (using ZIP) before sending it? Or would the CPU hit offset any gains in message size/memory usage?

Comment: As [signalr-performance](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance) mentioned that SignalR retains 1000 messages in memory per hub per connection by default. Have you try to monitor the transport your application used? WebSocket is the ideal transport for SignalR, since it makes the most efficient use of server memory. For more details, you could try to refer to [SignalR and WebSocket](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr).

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT, I'm currently working on reducing the size of the messages (by aliasing the property names on the payload classes that are serialized). Regarding the message retention, is that a buffer that is cleared as messages are sent to the client, or are they cached even after they are sent/received? i.e. how safe would it be to reduce that number? I could very easily see that being the issue, as I could have hundreds of simultaneous connections x 1000 messages x 20-30 KB per message...

Comment: Hi @MattPeterson, as Bruce said, have you turned on `Web sockets` in `Application settings` for your App Service? Without it, SignalR will use long polling instead of the websocket.

Comment: @AaronChen Yep, definitely. I've been tinkering with SignalR's DefaultMessageBufferSize setting over the last week or so (gradually reducing it from the default) and it has made a huge difference.

Comment: @Pawel if you want to write up your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it. That made a *huge* difference (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SignalR has a ring buffer where it keeps messages **per signal**. By default the buffer size 1000 messages so if you have many connected clients there is a lot of stored messages. (One of the usages of this buffer is to be able to send messages the client could miss due to a reconnect) You can try decreasing the buffer by changing the [DefaultMessageBufferSize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.configuration.iconfigurationmanager.defaultmessagebuffersize(v=vs.118).aspx). The minimum size of this buffer is `32` and [it is enforced by SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Messaging/MessageStore.cs#L27-L30) (i.e setting values below 32 will give you 32, below 0 will give you an exception). You need to play with this value - if you have a lot messages and the value is too small you may start missing messages.

Comment: Thanks! I changed from 1000 (the default) to 250 and that has made a huge difference in terms of memory usage.

Comment: I had the same issue, opened a an issue on SignalR repo:   https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3850 hopefully they are going to address this issue on signalR 3

Comment: There is no reconnect in SignalR for ASP.NET Core so there is no messages to be stored so there is no ring buffers anymore. You can read a bit about this here: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-13-design-considerations/